# why assistant interrupts my action with special intents?

Tags: actions-on-google, actions-builder

When speaking to my action on google sometimes the assistant interupts my
app, for example searching for the word, the user had used.
Why is the assistent taking action, allthoug i am in my App, asking for
users input?

Example: my action asked: "Are you ready?", the user responds "Munich" or other things. instead of the no_match intent, the apps assistent starts explaining the city or start other intents. But this happens only sometimes, with some answer . Therefore i assume that the no_match Intent is working in general. Is there maybe a setting to avoid interuption of google assitant when using my custom action?

[image: Scene that includes a NO_MATCH]

[image: GEN_YesNo intent]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely because you are handling those questions using the NO_MATCH System Intent. A recent change with how Actions on Google works means that the Assistant will close your Action and [handle the user statement itself](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/intents#no-match_yielding) under these conditions:

- You are handling it through a Fallback Intent in Dialogflow or through a No Match Intent in Action Builder *and*
- The phrase is one that the Assistant can handle itself

You don't get any indication that it is doing so.

To work around this problem, you should use an Intent that matches a phrase with the the `@sys.any` type in Dialogflow or an intent that accepts "free form text" using Action Builder.

Comment: Thank you! i will give it a try.

Comment: Good luck! If an answer helps, accepting and/or upvoting it is always appreciated.